# Extra border when "merging" two divs with round borders

Tags: html, css, border, border-radius

I was trying to do something like the [Instagram's "ask me a question" box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy4dV.png), but when the two divs "merge", there's some [extra border left around the title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZNdz.png).

What I'm doing wrong?

```css
.info {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.info .description-title {
    color: #f1ecff;
    background-color: #333;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 12px;
    user-select: none;
}

.info .description-text {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
      <h3 class="description-title">Descrição</h3>
      <p class="description-text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis quo omnis, culpa modi explicabo eius delectus dolorem a inventore, adipisci aspernatur laudantium voluptatum corporis vitae enim qui? Eveniet cumque officiis molestiae tempora mollitia quia id minima earum facilis recusandae voluptatum voluptatibus optio similique dolore nobis, ab excepturi aliquam quasi animi quisquam porro velit quam veritatis? Natus modi aperiam adipisci maxime.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKFGG.png)
try to make this changes Maybe it will work

```
.info {
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.info .description-title {
color: #f1ecff;
background-color: #333;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 12px;
user-select: none;
margin: 0;
}

.info .description-text {
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: hidden;
text-align: justify;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 20px 12px;
margin: 0;
background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved switching the `background-color` property from `.info` to `.description-text`.

Answer (score 0):

I read well the problem actually and delete the previous answer. Try to make this trick. Use a border in the info class and use the same color of the black area. Maybe you hide this little piece of white behind the black one.